# JAXB static marshalling vs JAXBContext createMarshaller()

Tags: java, jaxb, marshalling

I wasted a lot of time on the following code snippet, finding out where and what to put into my jaxb.index and how exactly to create the JAXBContext

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[]{GenA.class, GenB.class, ...});
 // or
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance( "my.package.jaxb" );
Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller(); 
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream( "file.xml" );
m.marshal( object, os );
```

But there is the static method `JAXB.marshal(object, "C:\\path\\file.xml");` making it as easy as one would expect.

I read that creating the JAXBContext is resource intense. Why should one use the first method at all? Any disadvantages of the static method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `JAXBContext` represents all the processed metadata for converting objects to/from XML.  Since it is thread safe you can create it once and reuse it.  This is a performance improvement over using that static method.